# How to serve WordPress plugin files (JS and CSS) from CloudFront CDN?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I'm setting up CDN for my WordPress site using Amazon CloudFront. I've successfully set this up `wp-uploads` folder.

Now when I check my website performance on GTmetrix, I see the following types of files remaining to be served from the CDN:

1. `https://mysite/wp-includes/*/*.js?ver=1.2.3`
2. `https://mysite/wp-content/plugins/some-plugin/*/*.js?ver=1.2.3`
3. `https://mysite/wp-content/themes/my-theme/*.js?ver=1.2.3`
4. `https://mysite/wp-content/cache/busting/something/*js`

Now I need to know whether it's a good thing to upload my complete plugins `wp-includes`, `wp-content/plugins`, `wp-content/themes/my-theme` folder to the S3 bucket (my CloudFront source)?

More generally when setting up CDN for your WordPress site, what all folder should I upload to my CloudFront source?

My aim is to serve all these files from the CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Install w3 total cache plugin and use cloudflare free cdn service for it.
After setting up cloudflare cdn you need to change your domain name servers to the cloudflare one.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm already using a plugin WP Rocket for the CDN integration. Do you think it will fine to use total cache plugin along with that?

Comment: Actually you can have a look on it. But as preference WP Rocket is a good plugin than total cache. You can also enable cloudflare cdn without total cache. Have you tried it?

Comment: My CDN is already enabled and I'm serving the resource from `uploads` folder using the CDN. I'm having trouble with JS and CSS because they are distributed over various folders - (different plugins and themes).

Comment: Cdn will not allow specific files to define. For faster delivery you have to use plugins like auto optimize.